# Getting rid of repeated point in plot

Tags: r

I am simulating traders and their actions and am trying to get rid of repeated points in the plot statement. What is the best way to do this? In other words, for  `ninterval >1`  I keep getting a plot where points are repeated.

```
 f1 <- function(n,m,priceinitial,delta,mean, sd, ninterval){
    traders <- vector(mode="character", length=n)
    traderscurrent <- vector(mode="character", length=n)
    price <- vector(mode="numeric")
    pricecurrent <- vector(mode="numeric")
    for(nint in 1:ninterval)
    {
      L = floor(rnorm(1,mean,sd))
      print(L)
      x3 <- runif(2,0,1)
      v <- c(0, min(x3), max(x3))
      for(i in 1:n)
      {
        traders[i] <- runif(1,0,1)
        if(findInterval(traders[i],v) == sample(c(1,3),1))
           {
             traders[i] <- "B"
           }
           else if(findInterval(traders[i],v) == 2)
                   {
             traders[i] <- "N"
           }
        else {
             traders[i] <- "S"
        }
      }
      print(table(traders))
      for(step in 1:L)
      {

        for(i in 1:n)
        {
          b <- sample(traders[-i], m)
          print(b)
          table(b)
          traderscurrent[i] <- sample(b,1)

        }
        print(table(traderscurrent))
        pricecurrent[step] = priceinitial+length(which(traderscurrent == "B"))*delta-length(which(traderscurrent == "S"))*delta
        priceinitial = pricecurrent[step]
        traders <- traderscurrent
        #print(nint)
        #print(step)
      }
        price <- c(price,pricecurrent)
        price <- price[-L]

    }
    print(price)
    plot(price)
    }
```

The call to generate the plot is:

```
f1(10,2,100,5,10,1,5)
```

[image]

The last three dots don't make sense.

Comment: Could you please complete the example? Give an example run and show the plot where you have the repeated points, etc

Comment: @Hack-R: I have added the graph of f1(10,2,100,5,10,1,5).

Comment: @Hack-R: Each run of  f1(10,2,100,5,10,1,5) will be different since you are sampling different random numbers. In my case, the last three dots shouldn't be there it seems.

Comment: OK, so by repeated you meant they have the same value of price?

Comment: @Hack-R: Yes, it seems that the statement <code> price <- c(price,pricecurrent) </code> adds the same price at the beginning of each L.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted, it's kind of hard to tell though without code comments or more context.

When you did `c(price, pricecurrent)` you did add a repeated point, for instance in my experiment `price` got set to `90` on step 1 then `pricecurrent` was `90 80` on step 2 and the result was `90 90 80`.

It looked like you were trying to fix this in the next line, but I'm not sure that it made sense to use `-L`, which was `9` in my experiment and thus had no effect on the repeated point. I *think* you want to use `step` there, but again I have no context so I can't be sure of the use case-specific logic.

```
f1(10,2,100,5,10,1,5)

f1 <- function(n=10,m=2,priceinitial=100,delta=5,mean=10, sd=1, ninterval=5){
  cat("I need to comment my code")
  traders <- vector(mode="character", length=n)
  traderscurrent <- vector(mode="character", length=n)
  price <- vector(mode="numeric")
  pricecurrent <- vector(mode="numeric")
  for(nint in 1:ninterval)
  {
    L = floor(rnorm(1,mean,sd))
    print(L)
    x3 <- runif(2,0,1)
    v <- c(0, min(x3), max(x3))
    for(i in 1:n)
    {
      traders[i] <- runif(1,0,1)
      if(findInterval(traders[i],v) == sample(c(1,3),1))
      {
        traders[i] <- "B"
      }
      else if(findInterval(traders[i],v) == 2)
      {
        traders[i] <- "N"
      }
      else {
        traders[i] <- "S"
      }
    }
    print(table(traders))
    for(step in 1:L)
    {

      for(i in 1:n)
      {
        b <- sample(traders[-i], m)
        print(b)
        table(b)
        traderscurrent[i] <- sample(b,1)

      }
      print(table(traderscurrent))
      pricecurrent[step] = priceinitial+length(which(traderscurrent == "B"))*delta-length(which(traderscurrent == "S"))*delta
      priceinitial = pricecurrent[step]
      traders <- traderscurrent
      #print(nint)
      #print(step)
    }
    price <- c(price,pricecurrent)
    price <- price[-step]

  }
  print(price)
  plot(price)
}

f()
```

[image: no repeated points]